# Tweening for 2d strokes in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

Is there any way I can tween my 2D strokes in grease pencil?

Answer (score 1):

If the lines share the same points (ie: copied keyframe and tehn used sculpt to push the line around) you can simply use the "interpolate" menu in edit mode, and it will VERY cleanly add inbetweens

[image]